# Object[] cannot be cast to Void[] in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, void

I'm getting this error inside an extended asynctask, but i'm really sure that Object[] IS a Void[].

This is my custom AsyncTask:

```
public abstract class RepeatableAsyncTask<A, B, C> extends AsyncTask<A, B, C> {
private static final String TAG = "RepeatableAsyncTask";
public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY = 5;

private int mMaxRetries = DEFAULT_MAX_RETRY;
private Exception mException = null;

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public RepeatableAsyncTask() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Constructs an AsyncTask that will repeate itself for max Retries
 * @param retries Max Retries.
 */
public RepeatableAsyncTask(int retries) {
    super();
    mMaxRetries = retries;
}

/**
 * Will be repeated for max retries while the result is null or an exception is thrown.
 * @param inputs Same as AsyncTask's
 * @return Same as AsyncTask's
 */
protected abstract C repeatInBackground(A...inputs);

@Override
protected final C doInBackground(A...inputs) {
    int tries = 0;
    C result = null;

    /* This is the main loop, repeatInBackground will be repeated until result will not be null */
    while(tries++ < mMaxRetries && result == null) {
        try {
            result = repeatInBackground(inputs);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            /* You might want to log the exception everytime, do it here. */
            mException = exception;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Like onPostExecute but will return an eventual Exception
 * @param c Result same as AsyncTask
 * @param exception Exception thrown in the loop, even if the result is not null.
 */
protected abstract void onPostExecute(C c, Exception exception);

@Override
protected final void onPostExecute(C c) {
    super.onPostExecute(c);
    onPostExecute(c, mException);
}
```

And this is the SubClass that gives the problem:

```
public class ListPalinasAsynkTask extends RepeatableAsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Palina>>{
    private static final String TAG = "ListPalinasAsynkTask";
    private static final boolean D = SystemConstants.ACTIVE_DEBUG;

    private ApiRequest.ListPalinasCallback mCallback;

    public ListPalinasAsynkTask(ApiRequest.ListPalinasCallback callback) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Called: ListPalinasAsynkTask([callback])");
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Palina> repeatInBackground(Void... voids) {
        /* Here i send request to get palinas */
        return Api.getPalinasNearMe();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Palina> palinas, Exception exception) {
        if(exception != null)
            Logging.e(TAG, "Received exception in Asynk Task", exception);
        if(palinas != null)
            mCallback.result(palinas);
        else
            mCallback.result(new ArrayList<Palina>());
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the error:

```
E/ListPalinasAsynkTask﹕ Received exception in Asynk Task
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
            at ListPalinasAsynkTask.repeatInBackground(ListPalinasAsynkTask.java:19)
            at RepeatableAsyncTask.doInBackground(RepeatableAsyncTask.java:43)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

I can't explain this exception because i'm giving Void as a parameter! That should not be an Object.
Do you have solutions?

**Edit**:
ListPalinasAsyncTask.java:19 refers to:

```
public class ListPalinasAsynkTask extends RepeatableAsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Palina>> {
```

RepeatableAsyncTask.java:43:

```
result = repeatInBackground(inputs);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm calling execute this way:

```
AsyncTask mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);
....
mAsyncTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solution found:

the problem was this:

```
AsyncTask mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);
....
mAsyncTask.execute();
```

I'm using generic AsyncTask to call execute, that class would pass Void as a parameter and will never call .execute() on ListPalinasAsynkTask, instead it will call ListPalinasAsynkTask.execute(Void). That gives the error.

Solutions:

1. Use ListPalinasAsynkTask instead of generic AsyncTask
2. Better one: Create a new class VoidRepeatableAsyncTask and make other Void AsyncTasks extend that one.

Like this:

```
public abstract class VoidRepeatableAsyncTask<T> extends RepeatableAsyncTask<Void, Void, T> {
    public void execute() {
        super.execute();
    }
}
```

Then you can easily use something like this to call execute:

```
VoidRepeatableAsyncTask mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);
....
mAsyncTask.execute();
```

This will call the no-parameters execute method of AsyncTask.

Comment: Perfect solution. The method call `super.execute()` is the important part here.

Comment: your explanation is not correct. correct one is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34400140/5455629

Comment: the same applies to super.executeOnExecutor(...) - make sure to include "super" to the call if you are overriding AsyncTask

Comment: This solution could be way simpler! Just declare it like this: `AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Palina>> asyncTask`

Answer (score 21):

An alternative way with which I solved it is to pass `Object` in parameters, even if you don't use the parameters.

```
new AsyncTask<Object, Void, MergeAdapter>()
```

and the override:

```
@Override
protected ReturnClass doInBackground(Object... params) {
    //...
}
```

The above applies (in my case) if you want to pass different types of AsyncTasks to a method and of course you do not care about the parameters.

Comment: Wow. That solved it for me. But I still don't understand why Void as 1st type parameter would give the "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]" error.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is much simpler as I see it.
Just create the subclass object in this way:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Palina> mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);
....
mAsyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Specifying the generics Type as void for the AsyncTask instead of leaving it off (or in my case as wildcards <?,?,?>) solved it for me.

Comment: You forgot an angel bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
result = repeatInBackground((Void) inputs);
```

instead of

```
result = repeatInBackground(inputs);
```

Comment: That way i won't be able to give a non-Void as input

Comment: @LucaVitucci You ask for a Void as a parameter... You're supposed to give only Void as input

Comment: You're suggesting to edit RepeatableAsyncTask that is a generic class, i'm not asking for Void as parameter, i'm asking for generic parameter A. I'm planning to use this class for non-Void also.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is occurring then you might have created a Derived class object and added its the base class variable (AsyncTask). So this error is occurring.
AsyncTask mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);

Lint also gives a warning when you do like this "Unchecked call to execute. Params ...."

The solution is 
ListPalinasAsynkTask mAsyncTask = new ListPalinasAsynkTask(callback);
Then call execute on it. It will work fine