# AsyncTask does not accpt data of type double

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i created an AsyncTask as shown below in the code so that the value to be published through onPublishProgress is of type double, but at run time i receive the below posted logCat errors

please help me to find the reason why i am getting this error

**Code**:

```
this.mbtnShowComp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mATComputations = new mATComputations();
            mATComputations.execute();
        }
    });

private class mATComputations extends AsyncTask <Void, Double, Void> {

    private int mI = 0;
    private double mResult;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.msg("mATComputations.doInBackground"));

        while (!isCancelled()) {
            this.mResult += (((++this.mI)/10) * (50));
            publishProgress(this.mResult);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.msg("mATComputations.onProgressUpdate"));

        mtvComputations.setText(""+(values[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.msg("mATComputations.onPostExecute"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.msg("mATComputations.onCancelled"));
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.com.bt_11, PID: 953
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.com.bt_11.ActConnect2$mATComputations.doInBackground(ActConnect2.java:1902)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    01-14 10:59:47.220 953-1958/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: What is at line number 1902?

Comment: @EricB. it is private class mATComputations extends AsyncTask <Void, Double, Void>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you: [Object[] cannot be cast to Void[] in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456117/5199320).

Basically, you probably have error in your `mATComputations` class and reference names (are they the same?) or you declared `mATComputations` variable as `AsyncTask` instead of your own class.

Please rename your `mATComputations` class to have proper Capital Name (eg. ATComputations).

Instantiating and executing the task should look like this:

```
ATComputations mATComputations = new ATComputations();
mATComputations.execute();
```